# Equivalent “окающие и акающие" translation in the English language?

Tags: phonetics

It's a question from phonetics and it's (I hope you recognized it) from Russian language “окающие и акающие, секающие и шекающие".

I've tried versions like “retaining the unstressed “o” and “a” and it seems to be wrong.

And there is another version, like "секающие и шекающие”, it is all very grammar oriented moments and needs special definitions that language may lack due to different family language and roots.

I hope I am wrong!

Comment: This is about linguistics terminology, so even though it asks for a translation, I consider it in scope, so I am voting to leave it open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is simply [called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction_in_Russian) "[vowel reduction](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2889/8b1c530433f5552662934981ea497989e86f.pdf)" in English: акающие or аканье (coming from the verb [акать](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian)) is "with vowel reduction (of unstressed о)", whilst окающие or оканье (from the verb [окать](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian)) is "without vowel reduction (of unstressed о)".

There is also яканье, which is usually simply transliterated into *yakanye* because it is simply a different vowel reduction to /a/ instead of to the standard Russian /i/.

The секающие vs шекающие just refers to dialectal differences in unvoiced sibilant production (cf. [sibboleth vs shibboleth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shibboleth) from Judges 12:5-6). These are called ["hissing" vs "hushing"](https://minpaku.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=repository_action_common_download&item_id=2960&item_no=1&attribute_id=18&file_no=1) sibilants depending on pedagogical tradition (e.g. for Russian and for Southern Evenki), but most phonologists would consider the first set "dental"/"alveolar" and the other set "alveolo-palatal", "palato-alveolar" or "retroflex" (etc.) depending on the place of articulation.

Apparently there is also [хакающие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA), where a velar fricative is used. Again, these would just be described as having /x/ instead of /ʂ/ or /s/ where appropriate.

Comment: French has a word _chuinter_. meaning "to pronounce /s/ as /ʃ/, but I know of no Englsh word with this meaning.

Comment: @ColinFine Is that 'palatalization' of /s/ to /ʃ/?

Comment: @Mitch Indeed, although its connotations are closer to English _lisp_; as in, it describes something as a speech impediment. It is also used to describe the screech of owls, the hiss of snakes, the [crash of waves](https://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/2002/05/21/ce-qui-change-et-ce-qui-dure-par-bertrand-poirot-delpech_276642_1819218.html).

Comment: @Michaelyus Then maybe 'chuinter' != 'palatalization' but 'palatalization' may be an answer to half of the OP?